# error while trying include liferay ide into STS (Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, liferay-ide

I am trying include Liferay IDE to my STS from Market place but I am getting error. I have attached the screen shots. Is there any other simple way to include Liferay IDE to my STS?[image: From MarketPlace]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other simple way to include Liferay IDE

Please see [Installing Liferay IDE](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-liferay-ide) documentation.

Particularly "INSTALL LIFERAY IDE INTO ECLIPSE FROM A ZIP FILE" section!

Comment: it is giving .tar.gz instaed zip, will that work or shall I need only zip archive?

Comment: Well for some reason that's what you get on liferay.com. I'm not sure if Eclipse understands .tar.gz files. If not get the zip from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/3.1.0%20M1/

Comment: 1. liferay-ide-eclipse-macosx-x64-3.1.0-m1-201612060357.tar.gz, 2.liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga3-20160804222206210.zip. These two are the file names for tar.gz and zip, here tar.gz file name clearly shows liferay-ide, where as the link you have provided for zip file shows some thing else, liferay-ce-portal-tomcat. I am not sure whether the link you have provided is liferay ide only or something else ?

Comment: The above link is to "Liferay IDE" folder of "lportals" project (which is Liferay) on SourceForge! In that folder there are 5 files - 2 for Widows (.zip) 2 for Linux (.tar.gz) and 1 for MacOS (.tar.gz) - those are the full IDE (with eclipse included). There is also "liferay-ide-updatesite-3.1.0-m1-201612060357.zip" which is probably what you are looking for.

Just in case here is direct download link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/3.1.0%20M1/liferay-ide-updatesite-3.1.0-m1-201612060357.zip/download